# why is std::cin not reading from the start

Tags: c++, cin

I was looking at a question involving how the `std::cin` works. This was the question:

What does the following program do if, when it asks you for input, you type two names(for example Samuel Beckett)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl << "And what is yours? ";

    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl << "; nice to meet you too!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be :

```
What is your name? Samuel Beckett
Hello, Samuel
And what is yours? Hello, Samuel
; nice to meet you too!
```

But the output is:

```
What is your name? Samuel Beckett
Hello, Samuel
And what is yours? Hello, Beckett
; nice to meet you too!
```

Can anybody please help, how `std::cin` is working ?

I know that if i do this:

```
    std::string a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
```

and type two words in, then `a` will have the first word and `b` will have the second.But why is this happening? Isn't `std::cin` supposed to initially discard all whitespace first and then read characters till another whitespace is reached???

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the following program do if, when it asks you for input, you type two names (for example Samuel Beckett)?

`operator>>` stops reading when it encounters whitespace (amongst other conditions). So, the first call to `>>` returns only `Samuel`, leaving `Beckett` in the input buffer for the next call to `>>` to return. Which is exactly what you see happen.

> I know that if i do this:
>
> ```
> std::string a, b;
> std::cin >> a >> b;
> ```
>
> and type two words in, then a will have the first word and b will have the second.

There is no difference whatsoever between

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

And

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
```

In the first case, `operator>>` returns an `std::istream&` reference to the stream being read from, which is what allows multiple operations to be chained together. But the same operations can also be done in separate statements, too.

> Isn't std::cin supposed to initially discard all whitespace first and then read characters till another whitespace is reached???

Not `std::cin` itself, but `operator>>`, but yes, and that is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: On  a side note, is ```cin``` the one which reads the character into buffer , and form the buffer extraction operator reads till whitespace???

Comment: @CeNiEi not exactly. It is actually the `std::streambuf` assigned to `std::cin` which does the actual reading and buffering. By default, `std::cin` is initialized with a `std::streambuf` that reads from the process's `stdin`. But you can always swap in another `std::streambuf` to read from something else, if you want. `operator>>` reads from the `std::istream`, which then reads from the `std::streambuf`, which reads and buffers as needed.

Comment: Thank you very very much! That was super helpful

Answer (score 3):

Stream extractors (`>>`) are whitespace-delimited - when it reads, it stops when it hits any whitespace. The next time it's used, it begins reading from where it left off. If you want to only delimit on newlines, you can use `cin.getline()` instead.

EDIT: Correction from @Pete Becker.

Comment: My question was why ```cin``` is storing different value for different variables , that means that for reading the next variable it is starting from after the whitespace. Should not it have started from the start of file again????

Comment: @CeNiEi The first time you read into cin, you give it `Samuel Beckett`. It reads `Samuel` and then stops. But `Beckett` is still there, so the next time you call it it continues reading.